# Data mining algorithm for anomaly finding in a restaurant business

Tags: statistical-significance, data-mining

Consider running a restaurant. During each shift there are approx. 30 people working on different positions (Managers, Waiters, Cooks, etc). Day in week, daily or nightly shift,.. At the end of each shift there is data about turnover, turnover in specified categories, # of products sold, etc.

**Which algorithm can produce results such as: ?**

- If employee1 && employee2 are on shift => # of Product1 sold is 230% higher than AVG
- If  employee3 && NOT employee1 && day=Monday => Turnover in Category1 is lower than AVG

Comment: These are going to bounce around randomly in the data, whether such relationships are real or not. With so many possible such relationships, any algorithm that searches over all possible relationships (ie, if you aren't looking at a few specified a-priori) will output garbage unless the amount of data is astronomical (ie, much higher that you could possibly get from a real restaurant).

Comment: Would it still be a problem if there would be a user input first? (ex. I want to see all anomalies for product1?